# node.js ejs include partial doesn't work

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm trying to include a partial in ejs but I keep getting an error saying:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/home/student/project1/views/('foot.ejs')'

I use this code to include it:

```
<%- include('foot.ejs') %>
```

The partial file is in the same folder as the `index.ejs` I try to include it in.

Does anyone have a clue why this wouldn't work? I did the same in other projects and it worked then. I use `"ejs": "~0.8.5"`

Answer (score 4):

Oke, I fixed it.

apparently the include syntax changed. Instead of:

```
<%- include('foot.ejs') %>
```

It now is:

```
 <%- include foot %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The current version of `ejs` on npm is v2.3.4 and using `~0.8.5` is limiting the version to be installed to `0.8.5` through the last version prior to `0.9.0`. Most likely you need to adjust your dependency version specifier so that you pull in a more recent version of `ejs` that supports the include syntax you're using.

Comment: Yeah. aldo I think  <%- include('foot.ejs') %> was the old syntax.